# Unit Test case to check if localstorage is empty once I logout of the Web app

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, angular-2+, jasmine, browser-storage

I am trying to clear my localstorage when I am logging out of the application. I want to write a unit test case in Jasmine to check if this task is performed when logout function is run. I am writing test cases for the first time so got stuck in the approach.

In my compoment.ts file I have a logout function:

```
logout() {
    location.href = "/";
     localstorage.clear();
}
```

spec.ts file

```
beforeEach(function () {
        var store = {};
        spyOn(localStorage, 'getItem').andCallFake(function (key) {
            return null;
        });
    });
```

I don't know if this is a correct approach to write the test case for this particular requirement or which one among unit or integration test cases is actually valid for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any I/O (in this case, local storage), you must have fallen into an integration test.

1. **A unit test** could be that when *logout* is executed, the call to
   clearing the local storage is made (using an spy on *localStorage*).
2. **An integration test** could be that you have data in the local storage and after you have logged out, you don't.